# Php. calc. начало 2.0 / g-avnocoding

Tags: php, denwer

нажимаю ПЛЮС (+) , как тут сохранить значения? чтоб потом, при нажатии "=" вывести их ? всё на одной страничке

```
 <?php 
if (isset ($_POST["plus"]) )
    {   
        $a=$_POST["nick"];
        $b=$_POST["nick2"];
        $c=1;
        }
$ab=$a;
$bb=$b;
if(isset ($_POST["answer"]) )
{
    if ($c==1 )
        {   
                $d=$a+$b;
                $f=$ab+$bb;
        }
        }
        ?>

 <form action="index.php" method="POST" title="qwe">   
     <input name="plus" type="submit"  value="+" >
     <p>
       <input name="nick" type="text" value="Число1"  size="20">
     </p>
     <p>
       <input name="nick2" type="text" value="Число2" size="20">
     </p>
     <p>  
       <input name="answer" type="submit" formmethod="POST" value="=">
      </p>
     <p>
       <input name="res" type="text" value="<?=$d?> <?=$f?> " size="20">
     </p>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну, неугомонный товарищ...
Чего пытаетесь добиться? Хуже написать у меня уже не получится.

Грубо говоря "запоминает" два числа и действие в этой же форме.

```
<?php
    $nick1 = 'Число1';
    $nick2 = 'Число2';
    $action = '';
    $answer = '';
    $result = '';

    if(isset($_POST['nick1'], $_POST['nick2'], $_POST['action'], $_POST['answer'])){

        //Добавить обработку переменных
        $nick1 = $_POST['nick1'];
        $nick2 = $_POST['nick2'];
        $action = $_POST['action'];
        $answer = $_POST['answer'];

        if($answer == '=' && $action != ''){
            switch($action)
            {
                case '+' : $result = $nick1 + $nick2; break;
                case '-' : $result = $nick1 - $nick2; break;
                case '*' : $result = $nick1 * $nick2; break;
                case '/' : $result = $nick1 / $nick2; break;
            }

        }
    }
?>
<form method="POST" title="qwe">
    <p><input name="nick1" type="text" value="<?php echo $nick1; ?>" size="20"></p>
    <p><input name="nick2" type="text" value="<?php echo $nick2; ?>" size="20"></p>
    <p><input name="action" type="text" value="<?php echo $answer; ?>"></p>

    <p><input name="answer" type="submit"  value="+"></p>
    <p><input name="answer" type="submit" value="="></p>
    <p><input name="res" type="text" value="<?php echo $result; ?>"></p>
</form>
```

---

Одного я не могу понять, если хочется нажимать несколько кнопок поочередно, почему не отрабатывать первое нажатие на стороне клиента?

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['nick1'], $_POST['nick2'], $_POST['action'])){

        //Добавить обработку переменных
        $nick1 = $_POST['nick1'];
        $nick2 = $_POST['nick2'];
        $action = $_POST['action'];

        if($action != ''){
            switch($action)
            {
                case '+' : $result = $nick1 + $nick2; break;
                case '-' : $result = $nick1 - $nick2; break;
                case '*' : $result = $nick1 * $nick2; break;
                case '/' : $result = $nick1 / $nick2; break;
            }

        }
    }
?>
<form method="POST" title="qwe">
    <p><input name="nick1" type="text" value="Число1" size="20"></p>
    <p><input name="nick2" type="text" value="Число2" size="20"></p>
    <p><input name="action" type="text" id="action" value=""></p>

    <p><input type="button" value="+" onClick="document.getElementById('action').value='+';"></p>
    <p><input type="button" value="-" onClick="document.getElementById('action').value='-';"></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="="></p>
    <p><input type="text" value="<?php echo (isset($result)) ? $result : ''; ?>"></p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ученье свет ©

Вот вам набросок для размышлений)

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
    <p>
        <input type="text" name="num_1" value="50" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="text" name="num_2" value="5" />
    </p>
    <input name="type" type="submit" value="+" />
    <input name="type" type="submit" value="-" />
    <input name="type" type="submit" value="*" />
    <input name="type" type="submit" value="/" />
</form>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['num_1']) && isset($_POST['num_2']) && isset($_POST['type']))
{
    switch($_POST['type'])
    {
        case '+' : echo $_POST['num_1'] + $_POST['num_2']; break;
        case '-' : echo $_POST['num_1'] - $_POST['num_2']; break;
        case '*' : echo $_POST['num_1'] * $_POST['num_2']; break;
        case '/' : echo $_POST['num_1'] / $_POST['num_2']; break;
    }
}

?>
```